# When activity is deleted, delete the corresponding custom object related record

Tags: apex, trigger

For the below code i'm getting an error in Helper class while deleting related records

=========Task Trigger=======================================

```
trigger Deleterelatedrecord on Task (after delete) {

    set<id> relatedids= new set<id>();

     for(task t: trigger.old)

     {
         if(t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == DeleteTask__c.sObjectType){
                relatedids.add(t.whatid);
         }


    }    
          DeleteActivites.DelOpp(relatedids);

}
```

============Event Trigger=======

```
trigger Deleterelatedrecord on Event (after delete) {

    set<id> relatedids= new set<id>();

     for(Event t: trigger.old)

     {
         if(t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == DeleteTask__c.sObjectType){
                relatedids.add(t.whatid);
         }


    }    
          DeleteActivites.DelOpp(relatedids);

}
```

=========Helper Class=================

```
public class DeleteActivites {

    public static void DelOpp(set<id> delacids){

        set<id> dids= new set<id>();
        list<task> tlist= new list<task>();
        list<event> elist= new list<event>();

    for(id id: delacids) {

        tlist=[select id from task where whatid = : id];
        elist=[select id from event where whatid = :  id];

        if(tlist.isempty() && elist.isempty()) {

           dids.add(id);

           }

       }

       **delete dids;

       // Thoring an error while deleting ids "DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Set<Id> at line 27 column 12  ""****


    }
```

Could you please help on this issue

Comment: you updated your previous question to include this question (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158953/when-activity-is-deleted-delete-the-corresponding-deleteactivity-c-related-rec/158973?noredirect=1#comment235603_158973). I have modified my answer in that question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong in this case (in `DeleteActivities`)

> DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Set at line 27 column 12

You're trying to delete a set of Ids, but DML `delete` requires an `sObject` or `List<sObject>` (or a subtype of `sObject` such as `Account`, `Opportunity`, etc...)

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a generic `List<sObject>` and then take advantage of the fact that you can set the Id in the `sObject` constructor. This will also remove the queries you have inside of a loop (queries inside of loops are a very bad idea 100% of the time).

the general logic looks like this

```
List<sObject> recordsToDelete = new List<sObject>();

for(Id objId :idSet){
    recordsToDelete.add(new sObject(Id = objId));
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code as specified by you but still having issues

for(id objId: delacids) {
        
       tlist=[select id from task where whatid = : objId];
       elist=[select id from event where whatid = :  objId];
       
           if(tlist.isempty() && elist.isempty()) {
                               
               recordsToDelete.add(new sObject(Id = objId));
                }
             }
**But it is throwing an error 
Compile Error: Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects at line 19 column 36 **